# Краш при получении значение из strings.xml Android

Tags: java, android

```
public String gate = getResources().getString(R.string.gate);
```

При вызове этой строчки происходит краш приложения.
Что может быть не так?

Comment: Выложите содержимое логкэта, пожалуйста

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7mx0AynV вот ошибка

Comment: нельзя getString вызывать с шампке класса. Только внутри метода/конструктора, где уже есть контекст

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало, когда переместил в onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Судя по ошибке, дело в том, что вы вызываете этот метод в классе, а корректно делать это в методах (onCreate(), onStart()). Так же как все методы связанные с Android-модулем (findViewById(), getActionBar() и т.д.)